# How to convert factors to characters using ```purrr:map()``` and ```mutate_if```` in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to convert factors inside list objects to characters.

My first attempt was a combination of `purrr::map` with `mutate_if(is.factor,as.character)` but this did not work. I Googled the error message but didn't find an answer to my question.

I resorted to using the `base::lapply` to get the work done (and it did).

However, I cannot spot the mistake with my `purrr::map` approach. 
**What is wrong with it?**

The following code is a working example of the situation I'm facing.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)

a_matrix = matrix(data = sample(100,100, replace = T),nrow = 10)

a_df = data.frame(a_matrix)

cut_modif = function(x) {
  cut(x,
      breaks = quantile(x),
      labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
      include.lowest = T,
      right = T
  )
}

# This one works 
myResults = map(a_df,cut_modif) 
myResults = lapply(myResults, as.character)


# This one DOES NOT work
myResults = map(a_df,cut_modif) %>% 
            map(mutate_if(is.factor, as.character))
#> Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars"): no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue is that `mutate` works on `tbl_df/data.frame`, the output from `cut_modif` is a `vector`, so essentially, it is a `list` of `vectors` and for that `map_if` can be used

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(a_df,cut_modif) %>% 
          map_if(is.factor, as.character)
```

---

If we still want to use `mutate`, convert to a data.frame/tbl_df and then apply

```
map(a_df, ~ cut_modif(.x) %>%
                tibble(cutCol = .) %>%
                mutate_if(is.factor, as.character))
```

Also, note that by making use of anonymous function call (`~`), multiple calls to `map` can be avoided

Comment: For the first time in my using SO I've been told to wait a few minutes to accept an answer as the right one. Thank you for your feedback, akrun. Very precise and concise yet insightful.